# How to enable the output to the screen for a bash command again

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, command-prompt

After messing around with >&, /dev/null, etc the BASH command `$ifconfig -all` does not echo anymore the output the screen.

How to correct this?

It's on the Debian OS of Raspberry Pi.

This what i get:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo ifconfig -all
pi@raspberrypi ~ $
```

Response on the answer of Robin Green:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ifconfig -all
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ exec 2>&1 >/dev/stdout
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ exec 2>&1 >/dev/tty
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ifconfig -all
pi@raspberrypi ~ $
```

History output:

```
657  # Copyright: Copyright (c) 2012 Kevin Reed <kreed@tnet.com>
  693  if [ -e $lockfile ]; then     pid=`cat $lockfile`;     if kill -0 &>1 > /dev/null $pid; then         exit 1;     else         rm $lockfile;     fi; fi
  696  echo $$ > $lockfile
  699  /bin/ping -c 2 -I $wlan $pingip > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
  753  sudo /sbin/ifconfig >>
  754  sudo /sbin/ifconfig >
  755  sudo /sbin/ifconfig > tty01
  756  sudo /sbin/ifconfig > tty1
  757  sudo /sbin/ifconfig >> tty1
  758  sudo /sbin/ifconfig >> echo
  759  sudo /sbin/ifconfig > echo
  784  exec 2>&1 >/dev/tty
  786  exec 2>&1 >/dev/stdout
  790  sudo exec 2>&1 >/dev/stdout
  791  exec 2>&1 >/dev/stdout
  792  sudo exec 2>&1 >/dev/tty
  794  ifconfig 2>&1 >/dev/stdout
  795  ifconfig 2>&1 >/dev/tty
  803  sudo ifconfig 2>&1 >/dev/tty
  805  sudo exec 2>&1 >/dev/tty
  806  exec 2>&1 >/dev/tty
  807  exec 2>&1 >/dev/stdout
  811  exec 2>&1 >/dev/stdout
  812  exec 2>&1 >/dev/tty
  814  history | egrep '>|<'
```

I see in the history that I accidentally inputted a bash script which shouldn't obvious putted there:

```
  648  #!/bin/bash
  649  ##################################################################
  650  # A Project of TNET Services, Inc
  651  #
  652  # Title:     WiFi_Check
  653  # Author:    Kevin Reed (Dweeber)
  654  #            dweeber.dweebs@gmail.com
  655  # Project:   Raspberry Pi Stuff
  656  #
  657  # Copyright: Copyright (c) 2012 Kevin Reed <kreed@tnet.com>
  658  #            https://github.com/dweeber/WiFi_Check
  659  #
  660  # Purpose:
  661  #
  662  # Script checks to see if WiFi has a network IP and if not
  663  # restart WiFi
  664  #
  665  # Uses a lock file which prevents the script from running more
  666  # than one at a time.  If lockfile is old, it removes it
  667  #
  668  # Instructions:
  669  #
  670  # o Install where you want to run it from like /usr/local/bin
  671  # o chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/WiFi_Check
  672  # o Add to crontab
  673  #
  674  # Run Every 5 mins - Seems like ever min is over kill unless
  675  # this is a very common problem.  If once a min change */5 to *
  676  # once every 2 mins */5 to */2 ...
  677  #
  678  # */5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/WiFi_Check
  679  #
  680  ##################################################################
  681  # Settings
  682  # Where and what you want to call the Lockfile
  683  lockfile='/var/run/WiFi_Check.pid'
  684  # Which Interface do you want to check/fix
  685  wlan='wlan0'
  686  pingip='192.168.1.1'
  687  ##################################################################
  688  echo
  689  echo "Starting WiFi check for $wlan"
  690  date
  691  echo
  692  # Check to see if there is a lock file
  693  if [ -e $lockfile ]; then     pid=`cat $lockfile`;     if kill -0 &>1 > /dev/null $pid; then         exit 1;     else         rm $lockfile;     fi; fi
  694  # If we get here, set a lock file using our current PID#
  695  #echo "Setting Lockfile"
  696  echo $$ > $lockfile
  697  # We can perform check
  698  echo "Performing Network check for $wlan"
  699  /bin/ping -c 2 -I $wlan $pingip > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
  700  if [ $? -ge 1 ] ; then     echo "Network connection down! Attempting reconnection.";     /sbin/ifdown $wlan;     /bin/sleep 5;     /sbin/ifup --force $wlan; else     echo "Network is Okay"; fi
  701  echo
  702  echo "Current Setting:"
  703  /sbin/ifconfig $wlan | grep "inet addr:"
  704  echo
  705  # Check is complete, Remove Lock file and exit
  706  #echo "process is complete, removing lockfile"
  707  rm $lockfile
  708  exit 0
  709  ##################################################################
  710  # End of Script
```

Comment: Even if you don't see, type `reset` and press `ctrl-J`

Comment: Didn't work:pi@raspberrypi ~ $ 
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo ifconfig -all
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ 
pi@raspberrypi ~ $

Comment: Wen you press `ctrl-J` do you not get a new line on terminal?

Comment: Yes, I get a new line but that isn't the issue. It looks like the output of the command isn't printed to screen anymore. So after performing the command I only see a new line again only.

Comment: Can you try: `echo -e '\0033\0143'`

Comment: Then I get 1st line clear, 2nd line the command prompt on a cleared screen.

Comment: But doesn't that solve the problem? Type `echo -e '\0033\0143'` and press `ctrl-J`

Comment: @user2976193 Please post the output of `history | egrep '>|<'` in your question. That might give us some clue of what really happened.

Comment: No, sorry it doesn't solve the problem, still no output from the single command "$sudo ifconfig -all"